# Ubuntu 16.10 logout takes too long

Tags: unity, logout, 16.10

I am looking for some solution regarding logout of Ubuntu 16.10. This takes about 90 seconds. Maybe someone knows and will help in solving this problem.
I'm a beginner. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I usually has to with one or more processes hanging.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday when I upgraded to 16.10. Turns out it was one of my startup applications that was taking a long time to shut itself down... it was **my-weather-indicator**. Do you have that? Cheers, Al

Comment: I turned off the My-Weather-Indicator, the fact he was the culprit of slow log off. Thank you heynnema and CelticWarrior for help. :)